# Do we have good APIs for cricket match scores?

Tags: python

I am trying to get full scorecard and statistics of the cricket world cup 2019 and matches of the past 5 years. I have gone through many but none of those are good enough.

I have gone with these while looking for any good source of free APIs (at least a few initial hit):

Pycricbuzz: But this does not give many choices. It is just for few and live matches.

Python PyCricket: This does not work nowadays.

Cricket API from Roanuz: Upfront payment and too costly. Though, I haven't tested it yet.

Cric API: It does not provide a full scorecard of previous matches.

Cricsheet: It do provide a lot of information but I need to download a lot of files on upfront.

**What I want?**

- full scorecard of last five years matches and other matches related information as we get on the cricbuzz website.

Is there any?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a research or tutorial resource.

Comment: I think I have followed the guidelines.
1. This is not off-topic because I can provide a link of some previous similar questions with positive votes
2. Question is not theoretical and it is solvable 
3. I have put all the required pieces of information to understand this question

Comment: If you think this is off-topic because of this links to the external site this where experienced moderators come into the play. they should have edited it. anyways, let me do it.

Comment: No, I think it's off-topic because you are requesting an off-site resource. It's unlikely that a moderator will look at this; but the site is moderated by a community. You are are free to post this and the community is free to up/down vote it and they're free to vote to close it too. "let me do this"; sure - you got your opportunity to post, and everyone else now gets their opportunity to vote on it.

Comment: See the "on topic" link, item #4.

Comment: @Prune item4 also says ‘show us what have done so far’ that’s what I had tried to show there. I had tried it in so many ways but none of those worked.

Comment: It says, "instead" of asking for an off-site resource.

Comment: Perhaps now it is being opinion based interpretation of item4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any such available yet. CricinfoESPN do have a plan to bring soon. Till then you can use web scraping techniques on crickbuzz or Cricinfo sites to get scorecards otherwise you can also look howstats website too for more statistics.